# subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier never being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

Following code:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    info.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = ^(CTCarrier *carrier) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"User did change SIM");
        });
    };
```

Inside:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

- Or no matter where I put the code just to test it.

No matter how many sim card I'm replacing on iPad Air Mini Wifi+3G with iSO 7.1.1 the event never being called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make global object of CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to hold a strong reference to the `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` object.

**Swift (iOS 12.0 and newer):**

In your app delegate class, declare a property for this object called `telephonyNetworkInfo` like this:

```
let telephonyNetworkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
```

Then put this in your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
telephonyNetworkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier = { [weak telephonyNetworkInfo] carrierIdentifier in
    let carrier: CTCarrier? = telephonyNetworkInfo?.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?[carrierIdentifier]

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("User did change SIM")
    }
}
```

**Swift (Before iOS 12.0):**

In your app delegate class, declare a property for this object called `telephonyNetworkInfo` like this:

```
let telephonyNetworkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
```

Then put this in your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
telephonyNetworkInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = { carrier in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("User did change SIM")
    }
}
```

**Objective-C (Before iOS 12.0):**

In your app delegate's `@interface` (or its class extension), declare a property for this object called `telephonyNetworkInfo` and instead of this:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
```

use this:

```
self.telephonyNetworkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
```

And then of course put this in your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
self.telephonyNetworkInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = ^(CTCarrier *carrier) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"User did change SIM");
    });
};
```

Comment: Moving CTTelephonyNetworkInfo object to AppDelegate solve my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: What do we do if we are Objective-C and iOS 12+ (iOS 13)? I've tried to follow this and it is not working.

Comment: I have tried (neither work): 
 self.telephonyInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier = ^(NSString *entry) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   qDebug() << "User did change SIM" << entry;
  });
 };

 self.telephonyInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = ^(CTCarrier *carrier) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   qDebug() << "User did change SIM" << carrier.carrierName;
  });
 };

Comment: @UserOneFourTwo You should be using `serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier`. However, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide all the code you've tried in a minimal, complete, reproducible example. Show where you've initialized `telephonyInfo`, show that you're holding a strong reference to it somewhere (like the app delegate, for example), and show how you know it doesn't work. Either we will discover (1) what you're not doing right, or (2) that there's a bug in iOS 13 that causes this to not work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you Tyler, I created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869036/objective-c-version-of-servicesubscribercellularprovidersdidupdatenotifier-for-i

Comment: @Tyler will this code work if i only remove the simcard ?

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora No, the `serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier` closure is only called when a new (different) SIM card is inserted.

Comment: @Tyler and also when application is running then only we can detect this right?