# Objective-C version of serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier for iOS12+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

There is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121684/subscribercellularproviderdidupdatenotifier-never-being-called) however it leaves out the iOS 12+ Objective C method. Here's what I have attempted:

Added to the application delegate:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo;
```

Then in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...

    self.telephonyInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];

    self.telephonyInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier = ^(NSString *entry) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            qDebug() << "User did change SIM" << entry;
        });
    };
    ...
}
```

But the code never gets executed (by breakpoint or log message) when I remove the SIM. How can i get the notifications in Obj-C in iOS 12+?

Comment: [It gets executed for me](https://i.imgur.com/WH3bwOF.png), but not when I remove the SIM card. I had to insert a different SIM card for it to get executed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming I am not crazy! I only had the one card to test with